# Client Service in different folder than Server Service

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've created node that has service in package (i.e. pk1). The associated headers files reside in `devel/include/<pk1>` folder. Now I need to create client service in another package (i.e. pk2) which needs to use the header files of service created in pk1. How can configure the project so that it can detect the location of service's headers automatically. I've added the full path of the header, I'm surprised this not working at all, which it should be from C++ perspective. Any suggestions? I'm using C++, kinetic, and Ubuntu 16.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389791/client-service-in-different-folder-than-server-service/) by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2021-11-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2021-11-01**:
Which headers are in the `devel/include/<pk1>` folder? Where is your service definition?

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2021-11-02**:
@Geoff headers generated automatically for .srv file. I do believe there are three header files (i.e. the request and response classes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the package for your client, follow the steps in `3. Dependencies` of [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/DefiningCustomMessages#Dependencies). This explains how to add a dependency from `pk2` to `pk1` so that your client can access the header and library files for the service.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2021-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The credit goes to @Geoff.
I will add my attempt to solve this problem so people should save their time if they encounter this problem. In my case, I've defined a custom message `ExampleServiceMsg.srv` in `srv` folder in package `example_service`. This package is a server that receives request. In this package, three header files are generated `ExampleServiceMsg.h`, `ExampleServiceMsgResponse.h` and `ExampleServiceMsgRequest.h`. These files reside in `devel/include/example_service`.

Now I've created a new package `service_client`. This package needs to use `ExampleServiceMsg.h`, a customized message generated in `example_service` package. To allow the new package to detect the header file, we need to the following: in `package.xml`

```
<build_depend>example_service</build_depend>
<exec_depend>example_service</exec_depend>
```

in `CMakelists.txt` for the new package

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS example_service)
```

---

Originally posted by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) with karma: 155 on 2021-11-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1